# Where can I find a complete list of all Ubuntu releases and life terms?

Tags: upgrade, lts, release-management

I am running Lubuntu and it does not have LTS releases, so I want to know if my version is EOL or not and what versions are.

I know of the [Releases page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) on the wiki, but that only covers Ubuntu, not any of the distros of Ubuntu, such as Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Kubuntu, etc. I also know of the `ubuntu-release-status` command, and that is useful, but could be a bit confusing for new users and isn't easy to understand.

Are there any pages that has a list of all the distros and their life terms, or **a** page **per-distro** separate from the Ubuntu wiki page?

Comment: @Braiam Yes, that *is* useful for finding about *just* Ubuntu, but it doesn't include any of the derivatives (Lubuntu, Kubuntu, Xubuntu, etc.)

Comment: Actually it does. "These release notes for Ubuntu * (*) provide an overview of the release and document the known issues with Ubuntu * and **its flavors.**"

Comment: @Braiam Where? I can't see that...I was mainly asking this because Lubuntu 12.04 *isn't* LTS like Ubuntu 12.04 as per this: "Unlike Ubuntu, Lubuntu 12.04 is not a LTS, this version will be supported for 18 months..." from [Lubuntu Blog for 12.04](http://lubuntu.net/blog/lubuntu-1204-now-available) so what you said, doesn't appear to quite apply.

Comment: `https://wiki.ubuntu.com/releasecodename/ReleaseNotes`

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know of. Maybe monitoring something like https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/ could help you.

For example, here's a quote from https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2014-January/000178.html

> Ubuntu announced its 13.04 (Raring Ringtail) release almost 9 months
>   ago, on April 25, 2013.  This was the first release with our new 9
>   month support cycle and, as such, the support period is now nearing
>   its end and Ubuntu 13.04 will reach end of life on Monday, January
>   27th.  At that time, Ubuntu Security Notices will no longer include
>   information or updated packages for Ubuntu 13.04.